# Different Referer Header setting in Firefox leads to broken websites

Tags: firefox, http-headers, http-referer

I noticed that using different Network.http.sendRefererHeader setting in about:config in Firefox ALWAYS leads to some websites not working properly.(On Edge, websites work normally)

Example:

Network.http.sendRefererHeader = 0

- Videos on embedy.cc don't have HD option, they only show in 360p (or
  lower)
- chan.sankakucomplex.com displays its posts(content) normally

Network.http.sendRefererHeader = 2

- Videos on embedy.cc play in HD
- chan.sankakucomplex.com doesnt display its images and videos, only
  shows thumbnails

I noticed it has something to do with me sending or not sending Referrers in http Headers
Header modifier extensions didnt help at all.
I captured http headers in both examples and compared them to see whats going on, but I dont understand that shit.

Is there a way that i can set Network.http.sendRefererHeader setting in firefox on per website bases, or to use some extension that would result in both websites working as intended ?

Answer (score 1):

found the problem, it is because i was trying in private window.
solution - set network.http.referer.*.pbmode in about:config to 1 or 3